# Dynamically appearing sidebar view/template when user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a web app with basic sign up/login functionality, a navbar which appears on each page, and several views for various other functions. I'm using ui.router for my routing and Bootstrap for my styling and grid.

I want to add functionality that causes a sidebar to appear on the side of every view *once the user is logged in*. All views are available to the user whether they are logged in or not, but the sidebar will not be present unless they are logged in. I have tried to implement this several ways, and finally decided upon using ui.router's multiple views function to accomplish it, although I haven't been able to make this work correctly, my most up-to-date code is listed below.

### Current Implementation:

In my routeConfig each state has a sidebar view and a content view. The sidebar view's templateUrl should either be null (if the user is logged out) or the location of my sidebar.html (if the user is logged in). As it currently is, this doesn't work at all and just breaks these states entirely.

The 'content' views are all loaded with ng-class functions that dynamically change their bootstrap grid-spacing based on whether the user is logged in or not as well, so that part works fine.

index.html

```
<!-- snip -->
<div class="container">

  <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
  <div ui-view="content"></div>

</div>
<!-- snip -->
```

app.routes.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    .config(routeConfig);

  function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, userFactoryProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url:'/main/',
        views: {
          'sidebar': {
            templateUrl: function() {
              return userFactoryProvider.getSidebarLink()
            }
          }
          'content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController as main'
          }
        }
      })
      /* snip - other states */
  }
})();
```

user.factory.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('userFactory', userFactory);

  function userFactory() {
    var _loggedIn = false;
    // will be either null or the location of sidebar.html depending on if user is _loggedIn or not
    var _sidebarLink = null;

    var service = {
      getSidebarLink: getSidebarLink
      // snip - other functions
    };
    return service;

    // snip - login/logout functions that modify _loggedIn

    function getSidebarLink() {
      if (_loggedIn) {
        _sidebarLink = 'app/components/navbar/sidebar.html'
      }
      // null if not logged in, sidebar.html's location if logged in
      return _sidebarLink;
    }

  }

})();
```

Comment: Way too long a question. We should be able to understand what your issue is in seconds...not sit and read a full page document

Comment: I've reformatted the question to be more clear. The "Considered Solutions" section remains to show my train of thought and what I've looked at so far. If you think it detracts from the quality of my question, please let me know how you think I might be able to improve it.

Comment: To be honest I think you nailed it using router and just needed a nudge

Comment: Have you tried using an ng-show on the  ```<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>```

Comment: You can create a service which will load html and related js file and will append into <div id="sidebar"></div>

Comment: How do I load the html and related js file from a service? I am unfamiliar with how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a ng-show on the sidebar:

```
<div ui-view="sidebar" ng-show="loggedIn"></div>
```

And in your main controller set this loggedIn value.

This can be done by watching a loggedIn event, or if you don't want to use events (don't know why) by watching whatever service takes care of your users logging in.

Events:

```
$rootScope.$on('loggedIn', function(){
    $scope.loggedIn = true;
});

$rootScope.$on('loggedOut', function(){
    $scope.loggedIn = false;
});
```

Watching:

```
$scope.UserService = UserService;
$scope.$watch('UserService.isLoggedIn()', function (newVal) {
  $scope.loggedIn = newVal;
});
```